# Automatic choosing of scales (linear, power, logarithmic) for legends

Tags: algorithm, math, d3.js, graph, data-science

This is more a data-science question than d3.js but I guess other people must have thought about that too.

I have a dataset with daily updating values. The set also contains the historical data of all or several days. Basically like this:

```js
{data: [
    "ItemA" : {
        "24.10.2020" : 123,
        "25.10.2020" : 134,
        "26.10.2020" : 145,
        "27.10.2020" : 156,
        "28.10.2020" : 167      
    },
    "ItemB" : {
        "24.10.2020" : 123,
        "25.10.2020" : 234,
        "26.10.2020" : 456,
        "27.10.2020" : 567,
        "28.10.2020" : 678      
    },
    "ItemC" : {
        "24.10.2020" : 123,
        "25.10.2020" : 136,
        "26.10.2020" : 149,
        "27.10.2020" : 152,
        "26.10.2020" : 165,
        "28.10.2020" : 178      
    },
]}
```

As you see ItemB is an outlier with values growing much faster than those of the other Items.

Setting up a scale for a Legend to display the growth over time was easy as long as the values grew at almost the same rate. A `d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, upperBoundValues])` was fine. While  the values grew the user could still differentiate between smaller an higher values.

Since one Item grew faster, the one with slower growth get pushed in one part of the scale. So if I had a color range like `d3.interpolateTurbo` suddenly most values get displayed as the colors near to black and one always to the red.

Manually I'd switch to a power scale or a log scale. Especially because I'd have to check daily for what happens.

I'd prefer to have a function that tests for such developments and automatically switches the scale if the values. Even better it would be nice to choose a *fitting* scale (Basically choosing the best fitting exponent of a power scale and/or base for the log scales).
I don't need a base10 log scale if my values will never grow to ultra large digits.

Is there any approximation function/algorithm I can implement that makes choosing easier, or that returns a value upon I could choose the scale (Like: 0...1 -> Linear // 1...n -> Log)

Comment: Normally, I'd say that you want to see the values relative to each other. And if that means that one line in the line chart is larger, then at least the perspective is the same. But it sounds like you want to know the *trend*, so you can see which line grows faster than the others. In that case, why not avoid this problem and use indexing: For every line, the first value is 100% and all points afterwards are relative to that value. You can still see trend, and you don't have to change the scale, because it resets every day to 100%

Comment: The trend plays into this, but is only relevant from an algorithm perspective. The actual use case is a map, with several areas (ItemA...) wich are supposed to be colored by the value they have. [The map has an timeslider Input for the timeseries]


If i have one outlier wich just grows different than the other areas, there will be a moment, where I'll have a lot of black areas and one red (to continue my Turbo-Example). I'd like to still differentiate the other areas to each other.


It might also be interesting to map this on a threshold scale with thresholds that make sense...

Comment: When you started about the map, I thought the same thing. I'd place the thresholds not regularly, but using the 1-9th deciles. That way, your turbo example will be red, but the others will still be differentiable

Comment: I've used something like that on a Covid-Map I did with incidence. I had to display different legal thresholds (0,20, 35, 50,  upperBound). Somewhen several counties passed the 50 marks but grew larger. I countered that with new thresholds on 100, 250 & upper bound. But the covid incidence will grow and fall in a mathematically more predictable way.

Comment: With this other scale, there are no predictions I can make. The only thing I can know is that there will be a few that might have high values, but most values that are similar to each other.
`d3.scaleQuantile()` with the 1-9th deciles looks promising but will probably fail if one outlier chooses to go logarithmic I guess. I'll try Quantile and come back to this. - Is there a way to get "nice" steps on those? (Like "100" is preferable to "99" as a threshold step)

Answer (score 3):

As an extension of my comment, consider the following, which uses `scaleThreshold` with the decile values. I've drawn 5 circles, and the first one's value increases much faster than the others. But you'll still see enough difference between them, because of the threshold scale.

```js
const data = d3.range(5).map(i => {
  let values = [1];
  d3.range(50).forEach(() => {
    // Either a multiplier [0.9, 1.2], or (if it's the first one, [1.2, 1.5]
    const multiplier = (i === 0 ? 1.2 : 0.9) + (Math.random() * 0.3);
    values.push(values[values.length - 1] * multiplier);
  });

  return {
    x: 50 + i * 100,
    y: 50,
    r: 40,
    values: values,
  };
});

const allValues = data.map(d => d.values).flat().sort((a, b) => a - b);
const colours = d3.scaleThreshold()
  .domain([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9].map(i => d3.quantile(allValues, i)))
  .range(d3.schemeSpectral[10]);

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", 500);

const colourbar = svg.append("g");

colourbar
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(colours.range())
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => i * 50)
  .attr("y", 100)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("fill", d => d);

colourbar
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(colours.domain())
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => (i + 1) * 50)
  .attr("y", 135)
  .text(d => d.toFixed(1));

const circles = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("r", d => d.r);

const labels = svg
  .append("g")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("dy", 5)
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y);

let counter = -1;

function colour() {
  counter = (counter + 1) % 50;
  labels.text(d => d.values[counter].toFixed(1));
  circles
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("fill", d => colours(d.values[counter]))
    .filter((d, i) => i === 0)
    .on("end", colour);
}

colour();
```

```css
text {
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Wow, very neat. I'll try this out and let you know how good it works for my use case. Even if doesn't I guess it might prove very useful.

Comment: I added a colour bar to the example, I think it might help illustrate it better